# Working with ICollection. Convert to Dictionary

Tags: c#, .net

I am working with an API that exposes an override like this

```
SuperAwesomeNinjaMethod(ItemToProcess item, ICollection itemProperties)
{

}
```

That's all fine and dandy except the `ICollection` is a dictionary.

How do I work with it as such? I guess I could pass in a list, but I would like to retain the association between the item name and item value so I don't magically pick items from the collection and assign them to **item**.

[Edit]

I apologize, my question was obviously unclear. The question I had was how to I work with an ICollection when the object passed somewhere in the call hierarchy is a Dictionary. Essentially I didn't know thatenumerating through the ICollection in this case would be enumerating through a collection of KeyValuePair objects.

Comment: What is this method trying to do? Sounds like you are using a base interface too far and need to percolate upwards a little, perhaps `IList` as you suggest, if your implementation is list-specific.

Comment: What is the question? Are you asking how to pass a dictionary to a method that expects an ICollection? Does the method expect a list of items or a dictionary cast to ICollection?

Comment: What is ItemsToProcess and what are you trying to do?  Dictionary does implement Icollection.

Comment: Don't pass in a `List`. Just pass in the `Dictionary` and typecast the `ICollection` parameter back as `Dictionary` in your awesome ninja method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to use that `SuperAwesomeNinjaMethod` with the indicated signature, and for the second argument, you want to pass an instance of `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, right?

The `Dictionary` class implements the `ICollection` interface, hence you can just pass your `Dictionary` instance. You will get a collection of [`KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tbh8a42)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are asking here, but if you need this method to handle dictionaries differently, you can test to see if the `ICollection` is also an `IDictionary`:

```
if (itemProperties is IDictionary)
{
    // Dictionary specific code here.
    var itemPropertiesAsDictionary = itemProperties as IDictionary;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the question? Are you asking how to pass a dictionary to a method that expects an ICollection? Does the method expect a list of items or a dictionary cast to ICollection?

In any case [Dictionary<>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) implements ICollection so you shouldn't have a problem passing it as is. If you want to pass the keys or values you can do that as well, by using the [Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yt2fy5zk.aspx) and [Values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekcfxy3x.aspx) properties. Both of them implement ICollection as well.

The following calls will succeed without any typecasting:

```
        var dict = new Dictionary<string, string> {{"aKey", "aValue"}};
        var item = new ItemToProcess();

        SuperAwesomeNinjaMethod(item,dict);
        SuperAwesomeNinjaMethod(item, dict.Keys);
        SuperAwesomeNinjaMethod(item, dict.Values);
```

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried just typecasting to the dictionary?

```
SuperAwesomeNinjaMethod(ItemToProcess item, ICollection itemProperties)
{
    // Just pretending your dictionary is string, string...
    var myDictionary = (Dictionary<string string>)itemProperties;

    // ... carry on...

}
```

You could typecast to `IDictionary` as well, if all you needed was the contract.